# Multilingual site: offer translation on same domain or new domain?

Tags: seo, url, multilingual

I have to translate my website in another language, and I was wondering: from a SEO point of view, is it better to have the translated version on the same site (like `/es/`) or buy another domain and create an exact copy with the new language (like `mysite.es`)?

Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate domain is better for the following reasons:

You can host a new website on a separate server, in the target country, which will improve loading speed.

You provide clear geotargeting signals for users and search engines.

Simple separation process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But from a SEO POV, wont my content be identified as duplicate?

Comment: No, if it's going to be in another language.

Comment: won't google aware that my site .es it's just a translation of another site?

Comment: It will, but it will still  count as a 100% unique content that serves to different audience